# Adding HTML to Document body not allowing for div click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the batman image is clicked on it shows the 'overlay' div however that div is not clickable for some reason thus not allowing the onclick portion of the code to run. Deleting the 'document.body..... ' line of code solves this issue but why?

### JS:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  $("#overlay").hide();
}


$(document).ready(function(){
 //page is ready

    $("#overlay").on("click",function(){
        alert("hi");
        $("#overlay").fadeOut(500);
    });

    $('#batman').on("click",function(){
       lightboxImg()
    });
});


function lightboxImg() 
{
  var source = $('#batman').attr('src');
  var text = "<img src= \"" +  source +  "\"  id=\"lightbox-img\"/>";
  document.body.innerHTML = text + document.body.innerHTML;

   $("#overlay").fadeIn(0);

}
```

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Lightbox </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightboxcss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "overlay"></div> 


        <img src="batman.jpg" alt="" href="javascript:void(0)"  id="batman" >

        <br><br><br><br>

        <p> RANDOM TEXT STUFF </p><br><br>
        <p> 328ueekfuuirgh40t43h8hohro8ht </p>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="lightboxjs.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle link or a complete example (images and css) so we can check with you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Use extended jQuery format like:

```
$(document).on('click', $(#....), function(){});
```

Check jQuery API for extended `.on()` parameters.

Comment: Welcome to SO and for helping! Note it's not "extended" jQuery format, it's called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).  Additionally, you should expand your example code to show the relevant bits from the question.  Lastly, this question is a duplicate, so as a good steward of SO, you would not answer, but rather vote to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: @cale_b thank you, I'll try to be more relevant in answers and terminology!

Answer (score 0):

Your handlers apply to some elements which are recreated when you append to `innerHTML`. You need to `.prepend` to body and have something like this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  $("#overlay").hide();
}


$(document).ready(function(){
 //page is ready

    $("body").on("click", "#overlay",function(){
        alert("hi");
        $("#overlay").fadeOut(500);
    });

    $('body').on("click", "#batman",function(){
       lightboxImg()
    });
});


function lightboxImg() 
{
  var source = $('#batman').attr('src');
  var text = "<img src= \"" +  source +  "\"  id=\"lightbox-img\"/>";
  $("body").prepend(text);

   $("#overlay").fadeIn(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.innerHTML = ...` overrides the element inside the body with new elements. The new elements won't have any event listeners. So clicking them won't fire any functions. So instead of ovveriding the body content with new elements use `insertBefore` like:

```
function lightboxImg() 
{
   var source = $('#batman').attr('src');
   var text = "<img src= \"" +  source +  "\"  id=\"lightbox-img\"/>";

   //insertBefore
   $(text).insertBefore($("#overlay"));

   $("#overlay").fadeIn(0);

}
```

Comment: or `$("body").prepend(text)` if you want to insert it first no matter what the first element is.